# Scrapy signals not connecting to class methods

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I've defined a `Crawler` class for crawling multiple spiders from script.
For spiders, instead of using pipelines, I defined a class, `CrawlerPipeline` and used signals for connecting methods.
In `CrawlerPipeline`, some methods require to use class variables such as `__ERRORS`.
I'm unable to implement the correct way for the same. Any suggestions or ideas will be very helpful.
For reference, I'm attaching the code snippet

```py
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from .pipeline import CrawlerPipeline


class Crawler:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
            'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
            'REDIRECT_ENABLED': True,
            'SPIDER_MODULES': ['engine.crawler.spiders'],
            'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
        })

    def spawn(self, spider: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.process.crawl(spider, **kwargs)
        self.__connect_signals(spider)

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.process.start()

    def __connect_signals(self, spider: str) -> None:
        pipe = CrawlerPipeline()

        for crawler in self.process.crawlers:
            _set_signal = crawler.signals.connect

            if spider == 'a':
                _set_signal(pipe.add_meta_urls, signal=signals.spider_opened)

            if spider == 'b':
                ...

            if spider == 'c':
                _set_signal(pipe.add_meta_urls, signal=signals.spider_opened)

            if spider == 'd':
                ...
            
            # These lines are not working, above two also not working
            _set_signal(pipe.process_item, signal=signals.item_scraped)
            _set_signal(pipe.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
            _set_signal(pipe.spider_error, signal=signals.spider_error)
```

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict

from api.database import Mongo


class CrawlerPipeline:

    __ITEMS = defaultdict(list)
    __ERRORS = list

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.__ITEMS[spider.name].append(item)
        return item

    def add_meta_urls(self, spider):
        spider.start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']

    def spider_error(self, failure, response, spider):
        self.__ERRORS.append({
            'spider': spider.name,
            'url': response.url,
            'status': response.status,
            'error': failure.getErrorMessage(),
            'traceback': failure.getTraceback(),
        })

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        print(self.__ERRORS)
        Path("logs").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        ...
```

Comment: I am not really sure what your trying to achieve here,  but your assignment for `CrawlerPipeline.__ERRORS`  should probably be `list()` or `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this! I know there are many things that needs to be fix, before that I need to connect the methods which I'm unable to. Currently, not a single method of `CrawlerPipeline` is listened or received by signals irrespective of their definition.

Comment: @Alexander I've created multiple spiders and want to use specific functions for each spider. So, instead of creating multiple pipelines, I defined single class for connecting specific methods according to each spider

Comment: I still don't fully understand, but what I can see is that your pipeline is likely being garbage collected as soon as it leaves the `__connect_signals` method, since you are not keeping a reference to it anywhere else in your `Crawler` class.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for helping me once again! You're right. After keeping a reference of `CrawlerPipeline` instance inside `Crawler` class, it is listening to signals and working as I expected!

Comment: @Alexander Finally, I came at the conclusion of defining `from_cralwer` method in Pipeline instead of creating mess like this, therefore, I do not need to define methods in `Crawler` class for connecting signals